# Unable to create a constant value of type 'ElectiveTesting.Models.ApplicationUser'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I get this message:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'ElectiveTesting.Models.ApplicationUser'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
    var thisUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    viewModel.InvitedToElections = db.Elections.Where(e => e.ApplicationUsers == thisUser)
            .Include(e => e.Electives);
```

I have read different of other posts on this subject, but havent been able to find a solution/work around.

Comment: And btw, it is a many to many virtual relationship. So i can't just say e.ApplcationUsers.Id == thisUser.Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the elections that are related to a specific user, you should use the Any operator:

```
db.Elections.Where(e => e.ApplicationUsers.Any(au => au.UserId == thisUser.Id))
```

Comment: Thx alot, that worked perfectly :)
This is my first time with asp.net, but this was the first bump i couldnt fix myself. But thx :)

Comment: @NWessel Great! :) Good luck!